# Highlight conditional formatting based on another range list

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

I am looking for highlighting the cells in conditional formatting based on another range list. Highlight cells if more than one of the strings matches the source range.

I have tried in conditional formatting: `=Countif(indirect("DD!A1:B"),$A2:C)>1`

[Worksheet demo](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qrf_3DBEqBRc5AfCSHMXZMHok0ldBGX4nfSiOBuYXpc/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, I misunderstood the post initially.  Hopefully, I understand your objective now.

You can try this formula:

=AND(COUNTIF(INDIRECT("DD!$A$1:$B"),A2)>0,COUNTIF({$A$2:$A;$C$2:$C},A2)>1)

Basically, the formula is saying:  "Highlight a cell if there is a duplicate in this range and it can also be found in DD!A1:B."

Here is a screenshot:

[image: Screenshot1]

If I remove "Apple" from Column B, "Apple" in Column A is no longer highlighted. See example below:

[image: Screenshot 2]

Let me know if this works for you or if I still misunderstood your desired results.

Comment: Thanks for your effort. Can you check one thing that mentioned in the question. Why `>1` is not working in this case? I need to highlight only if matches more than one.

Comment: I have modified my answer.  Sorry, I misunderstood what you were looking for.